# Update a column by subtracting a value between date

Tags: mysql, sql

I substract the column value but it not working..

```
avaroom

5
```

---

```
UPDATE `roomcalendar` 
SET avaroom = avaroom - 1 and 
day BETWEEN '2016-08-31' and '2016-08-31' and roomname='Standard Room'
```

when i run this query. the avaroom value change to 1. The result be 4.Why?

Comment: @sgeddes Yes bro.i need to wait 10 minutes. :D now done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are supposed to use `WHERE CLAUSE`

```
UPDATE `roomcalendar` 
SET avaroom = avaroom - 1 
WHERE day BETWEEN '2016-08-31' and '2016-08-31' and roomname='Standard Room';
```

**Simulating your problem:**

```
SET @avaroom := 5;

SET @avaroom := @avaroom - 1 AND 2 BETWEEN 1 AND 3;

SELECT @avaroom; Output is 1
```

<kbd>[**See Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/76784/2)</kbd>

Before setting the value to `@avaroom` variable the expression evaulates to a boolean value and in this case the expression always resolves into `1`.

Comment: Upvoted, correct answer -- perhaps worth explaining why the current query results in 1.  It's because the expression results in `true` which is 1 in this case.

Comment: Thanks @sgeddes. Actually I always try to add explanation. I just do it gradually.